# How to do sum of columns and make it available as column in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have following scenario on my data set. I need to sum of some column values without making any interference to other columns. For example,

Here is my data set

```
 data_set,vol,channel
 Dak,10,ABC
 Fak,20,CNN
 Mok,10,BBC
```

my expected output is

```
 data_set,vol,channel,sum(vol)
 Dak,10,ABC,40
 Fak,20,CNN,40
 Mok,10,BBC,40
```

Is there any way we achieve this without join.. i need an optimised result

Comment: You want to sum vol column value for all rows ?

Comment: yes.. i want the sum values for all rows.. is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("Dak",10," ABC"),
      ("Fak",20,"CNN"),
      ("Mok",10,"BBC")).toDF("data_set","vol","channel")

    val sum_df = df.withColumn("vol_sum", lit(df.groupBy().sum("vol").collect()(0).getLong(0)))

sum_df.show()
+--------+---+-------+-------+
|data_set|vol|channel|vol_sum|
+--------+---+-------+-------+
|     Dak| 10|    ABC|     40|
|     Fak| 20|    CNN|     40|
|     Mok| 10|    BBC|     40|
+--------+---+-------+-------+
```

Hopefully it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you..is there any way to do sum of specific columns ?? like if i have one more column "measure" i need sum(measure ) also along with that..